# Additional JDBC databases

Tags: quarkus

I am wondering about support for additional (and in particular less popular) databases, Informix, for example.

Quickly looking at the existing drivers, this does not seem to be a tremendous effort but I am guessing I am missing something.

What considerations are there to creating one?

Comment: Actually, there [does appear to be a JDBC driver for Informix](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/ids_jdbc_013.htm).

Comment: I think the question is about using such databases with Quarkus, but the only thing that suggests so is the `quarkus` tag. I personally don't have an answer :-)

Comment: The basic consideration that I know of, is that the driver needs to work in native mode as well

Comment: Use a database with no built-in extension or with a different driver: https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#other-databases